# How to change colors scheme in calendar heatmap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, visualization, data-manipulation

I am seeking some assistance in modifying my code to achieve color scheme shown in the below heatmap.

[image]

The above heatmap is adapted from the code [here](https://dominicroye.github.io/en/2020/a-heatmap-as-calendar/)

I have managed to produce similar heatmap, but I've got only blue colors. I would like the colors to be adjusted based on the temperature values. As shown in the above heatmap, I'd like the color to be

`darker blue` if temperature is less than or equal to 9 degree Celsius (tr <= 9)

`in the increasing order of lighter blue` if temperature is between 9 & 22 (tr > 9 & <= 22)

`in the increasing order of darker red` if temperature gets above 22 (tr > 22)

Here is my current code

```
# paquetes
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ragg)

# color ramp
pubu <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "PuBu")
col_p <- colorRampPalette(pubu)

theme_calendar <- function() {
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 1 / 2,
    
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_text(),
    
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
    
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.text = element_text(hjust = .5),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 9, hjust = 1),
    
    plot.caption =  element_text(hjust = 1, size = 8),
    panel.border = element_rect(
      colour = "grey",
      fill = NA,
      size = 1
    ),
    plot.title = element_text(
      hjust = .5,
      size = 26,
      face = "bold",
      margin = margin(0, 0, 0.5, 0, unit = "cm")
    ),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = .5, size = 16)
  )
}

# data

dat_tr <- dat_tr %>%
  rename(tr = temperature) %>%
  complete(date = seq(min(date),
                      max(date),
                      "day")) %>%
  mutate(
    weekday = lubridate::wday(date, label = T, week_start = 1),
    month = lubridate::month(date, label = T, abbr = F),
    week = isoweek(date),
    day = day(date)
  ) %>%
  na.omit()

#> Adding missing grouping variables: `month`

dat_tr <- mutate(
  dat_tr,
  week = case_when(
    month == "December" & week == 1 ~ 53,
    month == "January" &
      week %in% 52:53 ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ week
  ),
  pcat = cut(tr, c(1.8, 3:7, 9, 15, 22, 29)),
  text_col = ifelse(pcat %in% c("(9,15]", "(15,22]"), "white", "black"))


calendar_combined_temp <- ggplot(dat_tr,
                                 aes(weekday, -week, fill = pcat)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "white", size = .4)  +
  geom_text(aes(label = day, colour = text_col), size = 2.5) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorsteps(
    barwidth = 25,
    barheight = .4,
    title.position = "top"
  )) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("white", col_p(13)),
    na.value = "grey90",
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "white"), guide = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(vars(year, month),
             scales = "free") +
  labs(title = "Daily mean temperature (°C) durirng field trials (2014-2017)",
       subtitle = "Temperature",
       fill = "degree Celcius") +
  theme_calendar()
```

Here is the reproducible example

```
dat_tr <- dput(df2)

dat_tr <- structure(
  list(
    date = structure(
      c(
        16216,
        16218,
        16219,
        16221,
        16230,
        16232,
        16233,
        16238,
        16239,
        16243,
        16576,
        16582,
        16583,
        16586,
        16587,
        16588,
        16589,
        16590,
        16591,
        16592,
        16981,
        16982,
        16983,
        16984,
        16985,
        16986,
        16987,
        16988,
        16989,
        16990,
        17235,
        17239,
        17243,
        17251,
        17252,
        17253,
        17255,
        17256,
        17259,
        17260
      ),
      class = "Date"
    ),
    year = structure(
      c(
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L
      ),
      .Label = c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    temperature = c(
      25.15,
      19.875,
      21.4,
      17.4333333333333,
      21.38,
      20.82,
      19.7333333333333,
      23.3666666666667,
      19,
      22.15,
      16.3000003814697,
      19.8999996185303,
      20.8416665395101,
      25,
      19.1714284079415,
      17.7875001430511,
      15.6000003814697,
      16.3666664759318,
      21.2999999523163,
      22.6333332061768,
      28.2000007629395,
      24.5,
      19.5,
      21.7799999237061,
      24.1000003814697,
      19.6499999761581,
      22.8499999046326,
      24.8999996185303,
      23.7000007629395,
      21.0999996185303,
      10.7000000476837,
      1.88888888447373,
      5.04999995231628,
      13.8666664759318,
      14.5199998855591,
      14.9357141767229,
      12.447368471246,
      11.2146341277332,
      10.7999997138977,
      12.3066666285197
    )
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-40L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      year = structure(
        1:4,
        .Label = c("2014",
                   "2015", "2016", "2017"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      .rows = structure(
        list(1:10, 11:20, 21:30, 31:40),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                  "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-4L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame"),
    .drop = TRUE
  )
)

dat_tr$date = as.Date(dat_tr$date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still rough, but here's using `scale_fill_steps2` to come close to what you want.

```r
ggplot(dat_tr, aes(weekday, -week, fill = tr)) +            # use tr instead of pcat
  geom_tile(colour = "white", size = .4)  +
  geom_text(aes(label = day, colour = text_col), size = 2.5) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorsteps(
    barwidth = 25,
    barheight = .4,
    title.position = "top"
  )) +
  # scale_fill_manual(                                      # replaced
  #   values = c("white", col_p(13)),
  #   na.value = "grey90",
  #   drop = FALSE
  # ) +
  scale_fill_steps2(                                        # new
    low = "blue", high = "red",
    midpoint = 22, n.breaks = 10) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "white"), guide = "none") +
  facet_wrap(vars(year, month),
             scales = "free") +
  labs(title = "Daily mean temperature (°C) during field trials (2014-2017)",
       subtitle = "Temperature",
       fill = "degree Celcius") +
  theme_calendar()
```

[image: ggplot with gradient steps]

Changes:

- use a numeric value `tr` instead of a categorical `pcat` for `fill=`
- replace `scale_fill_manual` with `scale_fill_steps2`; other variants of this function exist, including `scale_fill_stepsn` (more than 2 bands)
- fixed typo `durirng` to `during`

Comment: Thanks very much for getting into this. I ran your code on my data - it's very close to what I want. However, the number of days in the week are all white, and thus hard to read. Could we change the color of days to black, please? I would be happy with the color scheme shown in the photo taken off the internet too if breaks are causing a problem.

Comment: Please disregard. I changed color to black in geom_text. Thanks

Comment: I didn't change the code setting `text_col`, which relies on `pcat`. You can try changing it to something like `text_col = ifelse(between(tr, 17, 27), "black", "white")` (tweaking the boundaries to find just what you want).

Comment: I was able to achieve black color by `geom_text(aes(label = day), size = 2.5, colour = "black")`. Just curios, what change do I need to make to adapt the color off the heatmap taken off the internet? It should be easier as I won't have to worry about breaks, but I can't seem to achieve that.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you asking how to get what we use as `"red"` here in `steps` to better match the color spectrum in the calendar plot?

Comment: Sorry. I am going to edit the question with the output of the current code to show what I mean. It's a bit hard to distinguish different temperature based on my current color scheme. Maybe my choice of colors is not good. If you see the first figure in the question (2021 mean Mediterranean temperature...) or this https://xeo81.shinyapps.io/MeteoExtremosGalicia/ , we can easily distinguish them. Maybe orange for lower temperature category, green for the mid category and red for the high temperature category will help distinguish these categories? I'm partial color blind, so maybe it's just me.

Comment: I understand, and it is clear that many good examples of plots are only good for those without color issues. Your initial question was how to handle the fill/color aesthetic with a gradient of colors, and I think that that has been addressed, is that right? It sounds like this new component of the question is how to choose colors (subjective) that look better; for this I suggest looking into the [`viridislite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridisLite/index.html) package, specifically intended for *"common forms of color blindness and/or color vision deficiency"*.